# Rails 3.1 - Displaying form values on Edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I feel like this should be really really simple, but I'm completely stuck!

In a form I might have a field like:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text" %>
```

On edit, this pulls back in the value submitted on create, that's fine. But I want to prevent certain fields from being edited. I know I can disable the field or hide it, but I'd like to be able to pull in the values to display and use in other ways. How do I access them?

In this case I've tried things like:

```
<%= f.track.name %>

<%= track.name %>

<%= @track.name %>
```

But none of the above work!

Any ideas folks?

EDIT: (I'm using nested forms for this)

```
<%= form_for(@release, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <h3>Upload Tracks for <%= @release.title %></h3>

    <%= f.fields_for :tracks do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'upload_track_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>

<%= f.submit "Upload Tracks", :class => "submit" %>    
<% end %>
```

And the upload_track_fields that are rendered:

```
<%= f.text_field :position, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.text_field :isrc, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.text_field :version, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.file_field :track, :class => "text" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :primary_genre_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :secondary_genre_id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :alt_primary_genre %>
<%= f.hidden_field :alt_secondary_genre %>
<%= f.hidden_field :asset_tier %>
<%= f.hidden_field :preview_start %>
<%= f.hidden_field :parental_advisory %>
<%= f.hidden_field :available_separately %>
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
```

I've hidden most of the fields to prevent editing, but still need to see some of the fields so they're left as text fields. I tried to disable them, but that stops any changes (specifically the file upload) working.

In short, i'd prefer to display most of the above as text rather than form fields.

Comment: How is the model being passed to the view? Does your controller set `@track`?

Comment: Tracks are nested attributes of a release, so it seems there's nothing in the controller passing to the view.....but how does the form manage to pull in the values??

Comment: Could you please paste the relevant portions of your controller into the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main form:

```
<% index = 0 %>
<% f.fields_for :tracks do |builder| %>
  <%= @release.tracks[index].name %>
  <%= render 'upload_track_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% index += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

In the nested form:

```
<%= f.text_field :position, :class => "text" %>
# Notice that there's no "name" attribute
<%= f.text_field :isrc,     :class => "text" %>
<%= f.text_field :version,  :class => "text" %>
<%= f.file_field :track,    :class => "text" %>
```

What I did in the first snippet is dirty, but I never used `fields_for` so I don't know how to get the actual index. I looked in Google, but I didn't find a solution so far.

I can't try it right now, I'll do it when I'll be home.
I suggest using this while finding a way to get the index.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that i'm trying to display the values as part of a nested form.....if I add a do loop as i'd normally put in an index or show I end up with double loops...

Comment: Well... You could have mentioned that you're using nested forms. Please show us more code.

Comment: What's the result of `<%= raise @release.tracks.inspect %>` inside the root form? (by the way, I'm not sure if it's `release` or `@release`, please tell me which one is correct)

Comment: Using raise throws an error but without it I get a hash of the tracks, one example: [#<Track id: 55, name: "a", isrc: "", created_at: "2012-04-26 22:15:52", updated_at: "2012-05-15 09:31:50", label_id: 6, user_id: 1, version: "", duration: "", parental_advisory: false, available_separately: true, preview_start: nil, asset_tier: "Front", track_file_name: "01_Track_1.mp3", track_content_type: "audio/mpeg3", track_file_size: 2719950, position: 1, primary_genre_id: nil, secondary_genre_id: nil, alt_primary_genre: "", alt_secondary_genre: "">,

Comment: Awesome, I had to change <%= @release.tracks[0].name %> to <%= @release.tracks[index].name %> and it works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As those who have commented said, I'd assume the `<%= @track.name %>` should work, if you have `@track = @release.track` (for instance) in your edit method in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping track of the index you can access the associated objects through builder, it's actually a track

```html
<% f.fields_for :tracks do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.object.name %>
  <%= render 'upload_track_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %>
```